# Binary Separation Distance (Java)

Tags: java, binary

My goal is to take two numbers and see what the number of differences in bits between them.

For example:

Number A:   01011 0111

Number B:   11011 0101

The difference between these two numbers would be 2 since there are two bits that are different.  Is there any easy way to do this calculation without making some big algorithm to decompose the two numbers?

Comment: You don't need a "big algorithm", you can just use a loop.

Comment: You might want to Google "Hamming distance".

Comment: (And you can XOR the two numbers together and then count the 1 bits in the result.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop from 0 to the number of bits you want to inspect (I'll pick 32), bitshift the two numbers by the current "bit index", increment the difference count if bitwise AND `1` (gets the first bit) of the two numbers is different.

```
public static int difference(int num1, int num2) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if (((num1 >> i) & 1) != ((num2 >> i) & 1)) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Example:

```
difference(0b010110111, 0b110110101); // result: 2
```

The number of bits to look at depends on your data type:

- `long` - 64 bits
- `int` - 32 bits
- `short` - 16 bits
- `byte` - 8 bits

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int difference(int num1, int num2) {
    int count = 0;
    int xor = num1 ^ num2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if ((xor >> i) & 1) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

And this version cribbed from the [Hamming Distance Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance):

```
public static int difference(int num1, int num2) {
    int count = 0;
    int xor = num1 ^ num2;
    while (xor != 0) {
        count++;
        xor &= xor - 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Simple implementation would be to convert both of the Binary numbers to string and compare each character like so:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < String1.length() && i < String2.length(); i++)
{
    if(String1.charAt(i) != String2.charAt(i))
        count++;
}
```

This is the simplest implementation I could think of.